# Want logarithmic scale on the x-axis of a plot

Tags: plotting, physics

I have succesfully plotted the running of the gauge couplings to one loop order with mathematica.

My code is as follows:

```
SMbetafunctions = 
  {g1'[t] == 1/(16*Pi^2)*(41/6)*g1[t]^3,
   g2'[t] == 1/(16*Pi^2)*(-19/6)*g2[t]^3,
   g3'[t] == 1/(16*Pi^2)*-7*g3[t]^3,
   g1[0] == 0.35940,
   g2[0] == 0.64754,
   g3[0] == 1.1666};

sol = NDSolve[SMbetafunctions, {g1, g2, g3}, {t, 0, 50}];

Plot[Evaluate[{g1[t], g2[t], g3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 50},
  PlotLegends -> {g1, g2, g3},
  PlotRange -> Automatic ,
  PlotTheme -> "Automatic",
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"t = ln(μ/μ_0)", "Coupling Strength"}]]
```

The beta functions are defined as

$\qquad \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{16\pi}\frac{41}{6}g_1^3$

with $t = \log(\frac{\mu}{\mu_0})$.

So am I evaluating the ODE's over the variable $t$. But I want to express the x-axis in the energy $\mu$ instead.

How can I adjust the x-axis to reflect the energy?

I have tried to rewrite the RGE's in terms of $\mu$ instead of $t$
giving me

$\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial \mu} = \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{1}{16\pi}\frac{41}{6}g_1^3$

However, when I evaluate this, I get an $\frac{1}{0}$ error with, e.g., {mu, 1, 10000}.

With python for example I can easily adjust the values of the x-axis by $\mu = e^{t}\cdot\mu_0$ and which simply translates the values from to energy and reflects it also on the plot.

As an example, plotted with python
what I have: [image]
What I want to get: [image]

The values of mu indeed range from $[\approx 0, 1E22]$

Edit:
Henrik's solution is what I was looking for:

```
LogLinearPlot[
 Evaluate[{g1[Log[μ]], g2[Log[μ]], g3[Log[μ]]} /. sol], {μ, 1, 10^22},
 PlotLegends -> {g1, g2, g3},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"μ", "Coupling Strength"}
]
```

in my case $t = \ln(\frac{\mu}{\mu_0})$ instead of just $t = \ln(\mu)$,
to achieve this one can just adjust

`{g1[Log[μ]], g2[Log[μ]], g3[Log[μ]]}`

to

`{g1[Log[μ/μ_0]], g2[Log[μ/μ_0]], g3[Log[μ/μ_0]]}`.

Comment: Probably ypu are looking for `LogLinearPlot`. `LogPlot` and `LogLogPlot` may be also of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the plot should indeed be adjusted to one of those plots.
However $t$ is evaluated in the range 0 to 50, while $mu$ should show the range 0 to $e^{50} \mu_0$, which is of the order ~1E22.

Comment: The relation between `t` and `μ` is not clear in your post. Please edit the question to give a Mathematica expression for this relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proposal without messing with the tickmarks: Just plot the functions you *meant*, namely $g_1 \circ \ln$, $g_2 \circ \ln$, and $g_3 \circ \ln$  (up to some constants) with a `LogLinearPlot`:

```
LogLinearPlot[
 Evaluate[{g1[Log[μ]], g2[Log[μ]], g3[Log[μ]]} /. sol], {μ, 1, 10^22},
 PlotLegends -> {g1, g2, g3},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"μ", "Coupling Strength"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Henrik,
this is exactly what I was looking for!
Thank you so much!

I did not know it was possible to evaluate to Log as the only thing that came to mind was setting

`g1'[t] == 1/(16*Pi^2)*(41/6)*g1[t]^3`

to

`g1'[Log[mu]] == 1/(16*Pi^2)*(41/6)*g1[Log[mu]]^3`

Which when I evaluate it says I don't have a correct variable, but I did not consider your alternative.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks ``:

```
Plot[
    Evaluate[{g1[t],g2[t],g3[t]}/.sol],
    {t,0,50},
    PlotLegends->{g1,g2,g3},
    Frame->True,
    FrameLabel->{"\[Mu]","Coupling Strength"},
    FrameTicks->{
        {Automatic,Automatic},
        {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log,Exp}],Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log,Exp}]}
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
xticks = {N @ Log[10^#], Superscript[10, #]}&/@Range[1, 22, 3];

Show[Plot[Evaluate[{g1[t], g2[t], g3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 50}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {xticks, Automatic}}]
```

[image]